# Enumerating directories for files(multiple extensions) with & without using MFT

Tags: c#, wpf

My goal is enumerating directories for files with multiple extensions. For example i will search an entire c:\ drive for files with extensions .mp3,mp2 and mp1. I know the fastest way of doing this in NTFS like file systems is using MFT.

My first question is;

I wrote a function without using MFT.

```
public static List<string> GetDirectoryFiles(string rootPath, List<String> extensions, SearchOption searchOption)
        {
            List<string> foundFiles = new List<string>(); // Start with an empty container

            if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                try
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> subDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath);
                    foreach (string dir in subDirs)
                    {
                        foreach (string file in GetDirectoryFiles(dir, extensions, searchOption))
                            foundFiles.Add(file);

                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { } // Incase we have an access error - we don't want to mask the rest
            }

            try
            {

                foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, "*.*"))
                {
                    bool correctExt = false;

                    foreach (string ext in extensions)
                    {

                        if (file.EndsWith(ext))
                            correctExt = true;
                    }

                    if(correctExt)
                    {
                        foundFiles.Add(file);
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { } // Incase we have an access error - we don't want to mask the rest

            return foundFiles; // This is it finally
        }
```

This function works but it's very slow even on SSDs. Is there any faster way to do this? Or can i improve this function to make it faster? I will use this on file systems like FAT32.

My second question is how can i convert this function to make it use MFT. I know there is a Project named "MFT SCANNER in VB.NET"(it's actually in c#)https://mftscanner.codeplex.com/. But i can't found out how can i use it for my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done a fair amount of this, and while you can get some good speed increases when you use FS-specific methods like MFT enumeration doing so takes a lot of work and often requires elevated privileges to function.  I try to avoid that as a general rule.  It also means you have to do various tests to determine which of your many enumerators will work for you in a particular instance.  Better to let the OS handle all of that... that's why we have abstraction layers :)

The fastest general-purpose method I've found is to call the Windows `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` APIs directly.  This works on all files systems supported by Windows, including network-connected ones.

Here's some code from one of my old projects:

```
public sealed class SafeFindHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr handle);

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
    internal SafeFindHandle()
        : base(true)
    { }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        if (IsInvalid)
            return true;
        return FindClose(base.handle);
    }
}

public static class FileEnumerator
{
    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto), BestFitMapping(false)]
    internal class WIN32_FIND_DATA
    {
        public FileAttributes dwFileAttributes;
        public uint ftCreationTime_dwLowDateTime;
        public uint ftCreationTime_dwHighDateTime;
        public uint ftLastAccessTime_dwLowDateTime;
        public uint ftLastAccessTime_dwHighDateTime;
        public uint ftLastWriteTime_dwLowDateTime;
        public uint ftLastWriteTime_dwHighDateTime;
        public uint nFileSizeHigh;
        public uint nFileSizeLow;
        public int dwReserved0;
        public int dwReserved1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string cFileName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
        public string cAlternateFileName;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern SafeFindHandle FindFirstFile(string fileName,
        [In, Out] WIN32_FIND_DATA data);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool FindNextFile(SafeFindHandle hndFindFile,
        [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA finddata = new WIN32_FIND_DATA();
        Queue<string> paths = new Queue<string>();
        paths.Enqueue(path);

        while (paths.Count > 0)
        {
            var nxtpath = paths.Dequeue();

            using (var fh = FindFirstFile(Path.Combine(nxtpath, "*"), finddata))
            {
                if (fh.IsInvalid)
                    continue;
                bool ok = true;
                while (ok)
                {
                    if ((finddata.dwFileAttributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
                    {
                        if (finddata.cFileName != "." && finddata.cFileName != "..")
                            paths.Enqueue(Path.Combine(nxtpath, finddata.cFileName));
                    }
                    else
                        yield return Path.Combine(nxtpath, finddata.cFileName);

                    ok = FindNextFile(fh, finddata);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you an enumerable of file names that you can filter with standard LINQ constructs:

```
var filenames = FileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Some\Folder")
    .Where(fn => string.Compare(Path.GetExtension(fn), ".txt", true) == 0);
```

Of course if you want to return more than just filenames you just need to figure out which bits of information from the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` class are of interest and return those.  Saves a lot of time if you can get it all at once rather than having to create a `FileInfo` instance for each file.

Comment: Wow. This is really a lot faster than my function. I think the only downside is i saw memory usage goes up to ~450 mb. I think it may run out of memory with the combination of a computer with low amount of memory and a drive big enough.

Comment: Yeap i have a problem here :) . I just use your class multiple times and application crashed when it reached ~2gb memory. Is there a way to release memory used by your class after each file enumeration ?

Comment: @c36ab7c4 Ooops... looks like the `SafeFindHandle` isn't disposing properly.  Just take out the condition in `ReleaseHandle()` so that it always calls `FindClose(base.handle);`  That should keep the memory usage down.